# Find out who is smb browse master

Tags: debian, samba, smb

Hy, i have a netgear nas (debian) which i like to have as smb browse master.
But i have the suspicion that the windows 7 notebook grab this role.

How can i figure out who is actualy the brwose master?

The proble is that the samsung blue ray player dosent find the nas storrage.

Is it possible that i have more then one machine in network that takes the browse master role?

My smb.conf

```
[global]
 browseable = 1
 hostname lookups = 1
 os level = 255
 wins support = Yes
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 domain master = Yes
 dns proxy = Yes
 preferred master = Yes
 local master = Yes 
 hostname lookups = 1
 dos charset = CP437
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nbtstat` to find out the computer which is the browsing master. Syntax: `nbtstat -a COMPUTER-NAME`. The output should contain something like `MSBROWSE`

Sadly, you have to do this for every single computer in your network.

**edit**

To view all computers in your current domain, use `net view`. To view a list of existing domains in your network, use `net use /domain`.

Comment: Thaks for answer here the result: http://pastebin.com/PPqdgJnK

Comment: It seams the NAS is brose master, like i want to have it. But what is crazy, is that my problem child, the dvd player is not listed there. And nbstat -A 192.168.50.53 gives also no result. The problem is that the dvd player only shows smb shares from notebook but not from nas but the notebooks shows the nas shares. But if the notebook is browse master everythink works.

Comment: I recommend moving this question to superuser. This has nothing to do with programming etc. and my knowledge about SMD ends here too.